# Change text based on state of script (expanded or collapsed)

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the static "Show/Hide announcement" title to dynamically "Show Announcement" or "Hide Announcement" based on whether its collapsed or expanded. Currently it just shows the "Show/Hide announcement" no matter whether the content is collapsed or expanded and i would like to change it to dynamic.

My Code:

```
    <div class="collapsibleContainer" title="Show/Hide Announcement">
        <img src="images/announce.jpg" />
    </div>
```

My Script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsibleContainer").collapsiblePanel();
    });
</script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
        // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
        return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);


function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-widget");

    // Check if there are any child elements, if not then wrap the inner text within a new div.
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
    $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>");
    }    

    // Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='collapsibleContainerContent ui-widget-content'></div>");

    // Create a new div as the first item within the container.  Put the title of the panel in here.
    $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle ui-widget-header'><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));



    // Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new title div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);
}


function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    // The item clicked is the title div... get this parent (the overall container) and toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}

</script>
```

My CSS:

```
.collapsibleContainer
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.collapsibleContainerTitle
{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.collapsibleContainerTitle div
{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Capriola';
    font-weight: 400;
    background-images: url(images/bg.png);
}
```

My updated CSS to show opacity, but it changes the text. i only want the background and the border to be faded out. on hover to be at 1.0:

```
.collapsibleContainerTitle div
{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Capriola';
    font-weight: 400;
    background-images: url(images/bg.png);
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.collapsibleContainerTitle div:hover
{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Capriola';
    font-weight: 400;
    background-images: url(images/bg.png);
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle(function() {
        $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", $(this).parent()).children(':first')
           .text($(this).is(':visible')?'Hide Announcement':'Show Announcement');
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7WKXm/1/)

Comment: Also if you can assist me with taking a little further on it. The opacity hover should be 1.0 and when the mouse is not on the DIV, i want the opacity to be low so it doesn't stand out. the background image only. any help on that?

Comment: @Interfaith - Not sure I understand, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7WKXm/2/) ???

Comment: If it's the same element that contains the text, and all you want is to fade the background image, you can't do that! You could fade out a background color with rgba colors (not cross browser), but not with an image, then you'll need two elements, one with the background image and one with the text, as there is no good way to fade just the background image other than using two images where one is faded and one is not, and setting different background images in the :hover CSS. Also, you only need the CSS statements that you intend to change in the :hover statement, not all of them.

Comment: i cant use something like they have here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Sure you can, if it's an actual image element and not a background image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move this script block

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsibleContainer").collapsiblePanel();
    });
</script>
```

below the second block of script.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EWJby/